# How do I access the SOAPAction property of a Soap web request?

Tags: groovy, soapui

Hi I am using a SoapUI Pro to test a set of Soap web services.

I have a testRunListener that logs the requests and responses of my soap requests to a file that it creates when the test is run. In this I have an if statement which checks the name of the test step before logging the request and response ..

```
if(testStepResult.testStep.label==("createShipment_1") || testStepResult.testStep.label==    ("printLabel_1") 
|| testStepResult.testStep.label==("updateShipment_1_StatusAllocated") || testStepResult.testStep.label==    ("cancelShipment")
```

rather than using the names of the individual requests I would like to use something more generic like the type of the request which could be createShipment or cancelShipment. This is because I have multiple test steps that use the same request type but are named differently e.g. printLabel_shipmentStatusCancelled etc and I don't want to list all of these in the if statement conditions.

I see in the info that gets logged to the file there is a property called 'SOAPAction' which is the type of request, in my case (createShipment, cancelShipment, printLabel) etc.

```
---------------- Request ---------------------------
Request Headers: Host : testapi.royalmail.com
Content-Length : 1718
SOAPAction : "cancelShipment"
Accept-Encoding : gzip,deflate
User-Agent : Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Connection : Keep-Alive
Content-Type : text/xml;charset=UTF-8
```

My question is how do I access this property so that I can use it in my groovy script 'if condition'?

I see that this also appears in SoapUI Pro in the TestRequest Properties and is called 'Operation'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Smartbear regarding this and their solution was to use the testStep property "Response"

```
if( context.currentStep.hasProperty("Response") ){testStepResult.writeTo(pw)}
```

Tested this and it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `operation` in the properties of the test step request is the `wsdl:operation` not the `SOAPAction`, the `SOAPAction` is defined as an attribute of `soap:operation` in the wsdl and passed as http header in the test step request, look at the follow fragment of the wsdl description to see the differences:

```
 <wsdl:operation name="myOperation" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <soap:operation soapAction="mySoapAction" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
```

So to get the `SOAPAction` with groovy test step get all http headers of the request and then select the `SOAPAction` as follows:

```
// get the test request
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Test Request")
// execute
def testStepResult = testStep.run(testRunner,context)
// get the header, and get the SOAPACtion
def headers = testStepResult.requestHeaders
def soapAction = headers.get("SOAPAction")
log.info soapAction
```

Note that I suppose that `testStepResult` which you use in your question is an instance of [com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStepResult](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlTestRequestStepResult.html)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the solution and apologies for my late reply. I think I asked the wrong question so haven't bothered to try  out your solution, sorry for wasting your time there . I am logging the request and responses of my SoapUI Pro tests to a file. What I'd like to do is restrict this to just the soap web service requests and not log the property transfer, data source and groovy script steps, which it currently does. Is there anyway to filter on one of the web service request properties so that it only logs these?

Comment: Hi @tamnorris no problem `:)`. How are you logging your request and responses to a file, with a `groovy` script or with `Launch TestRunner` option and using `Reports` tab options?

Comment: Hi. I'm using a TestRunListener.afterStep event (from Events tab) with the code ..fos = new FileOutputStream(inputFileResponse, true )
pw = new PrintWriter( fos )
testStepResult.writeTo( pw ).

Comment: Ah ok, I don't have this tab because I'm using a free version, however I think that a possible way to do so is to check the class of your `testStepResult` before write it to a file with `testStepResult.writeTo`. If you want to save only the SOAP `testSteps` check that the class of `testStepResult` is `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStepResult` with the following code: `if(testStepResult instanceof com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStepResult){testStepResult.writeTo(pw)}`. (1/2)

Comment: Check all implemented classes for `testStepResult` interface: http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestStepResult.html, and save only your desired testStep results using `instanceof`. Hope this helps. (2/2).

Comment: Hi. Apologies again for late reply, but unfortunately this didn't work. I might go direct to Smartbear. If I get an answer then I will let you know. There is a property for each of the test steps that is basically the name of the request e.g. createShipment, printLabel, cancelShipment. If I could find out how to access this I could use this to filter out the requests I don't want.

Comment: @tamnorris I'm not sure that I understand you, however each testStep has a property with key `name` which its value is the name of the testStep. Anywise if the solution from my old comments didn't help you, maybe you can try asking another question maybe someone knows the answer `:)`.

Comment: Yeah sorry I don't think I worded my questions very well. But the reason I can't use the name property is because a lot of my test cases have a unique name for the same request e.g. createShipment_international, createShipment_domestic and I want to avoid having to list all the unique names in the groovy script. Smartbear came back to me with a solution. I can use the property "Response" to filter out test steps I don't want to log "if( context.currentStep.hasProperty("Response") ){testStepResult.writeTo(pw)}. Thanks again for your help.